# How to encode large number of unique categorical values?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning, normalization

I have a dataset with a few columns that have around **18000** unique values each.

It is impossible to use `one_hot` because it blows up in dimensionality and also runs out of memory.

A simple `label_encoder` will still have values from `{0, 18000}` so it not ideal. Perhaps, this can be normalized between two values i.e.: `{-1, 1}`.

How would one handle this issue?

**Edit**
Came up with this - don't know if its correct

```
class OrdinalEncoderAndStandardScalerTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, mean=None, var=None, encoding_dict=None):
        self.mean = mean
        self.var = var
        self.encoding_dict = encoding_dict

    def fit(self, x, y=None):
        self.ordinal_encoder = OrdinalEncoder()
        self.scaler = StandardScaler()
        return self

    def transform(self, x, y=None):
        series_name = x.name
        _x = x.to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)
        _x = self.ordinal_encoder.fit_transform(_x)
        categories = self.ordinal_encoder.categories_
        self.encoding_dict = dict(zip((categories[0]), range(len(categories[0]))))
        _x = np.squeeze(self.scaler.fit_transform(_x))
        self.mean = self.scaler.mean_[0]
        self.var = self.scaler.var_[0]
        return pd.Series(_x, name=series_name)
```

Comment: You should apply some manual and personal preprocess. For example, if your column is "jobs", one solution should be grouping jobs, like Engineering jobs, Scientist jobs,... Then, number of different classes will be drastically reduced. However, it depends on the columns, but for sure you can apply some of these transformation. Of course, making this grouping will make you loose a little bit of information.

Comment: @AlexSerraMarrugat I tried OrdinalEncoding then I followed with a StandardScaler - so I got the z-score. So to inverse - I would use the mean/var to inverse then lookup the encoding. Do you see any issue with this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the order is not meaningful, two possible ways come to mind:

- leave one out variety of mean target encoding (with cardinality this high, target leakage is a serious concern, so other varieties might be unsuitable);
- hashing (allows for memory conservation vs some information loss tradeoff).

There's a nice flowchart for encoding method selection at https://innovation.alteryx.com/encode-smarter/